# Propiedad Required dependiente de otro campo

Tags: javascript, html

Soy nuevo con el tema de html y javascript, tengo una consulta sobre como podria hacer para que dependiendo del valor de un select<>, se active en otro select la propiedad required, adjunto los dos select en cuestion , si el select 1 tiene el valor procede en el select 2 se deshabilite la propiedad required si la respuesta es no procede recien se active como podria hacer, muchas gracias saludos

```html
<label for="pais">Resultado de Gestion</label>
<select id="cmb3" name="cmb3" tabindex="6" id="mySelect" required="required">
                                    <option value="">Selecciona...></option>                                   
                                    <option value="PROCEDE">PROCEDE</option>
                                    <option value="NO PROCEDE">NO PROCEDE</option>
                                </select>
<br>
<label for="pais">Motivo no venta</label>
<select id="cmb4" name="cmb4" tabindex="7" id="mySelect" disabled>
                                    <option value="">Selecciona...></option>                                      
                                    <option value="CARGO FIJO ELEVADO">CARGO FIJO ELEVADO</option>
                                    <option value="CLIENTE CORTA LA LLAMADA">CLIENTE CORTA LA LLAMADA</option>
                                    <option value="VELOCIDAD OFRECIDA NO SE EJECUTA">VELOCIDAD OFRECIDA NO SE EJECUTA</option>
                                    <option value="MENOS MINUTOS EN LA LINEA FIJA">MENOS MINUTOS EN LA LINEA FIJA</option>
                                    <option value="SE VOLVERA A COMUNICAR">SE VOLVERA A COMUNICAR</option>
                                    <option value="PROBLEMAS TECNICOS RECURRENTES">PROBLEMAS TECNICOS RECURRENTES</option>
                                </select>
```

Comment: la solución la necesitas en es5 puro? o buscas algo en particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hice este código a lo que entendí de tu pregunta, pero creo que cuando dices cambiar el atributo 'required' te refieres a cambiar la propiedad disabled, pero igual lo integre en el código espero te funcione

## CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT

```
// traemos de DOM el select mediante su id
var select1 = document.getElementById('cmb3');
var select2 = document.getElementById('cmb4');
// le ponemos un evento que se ejecuta al cambiar la
// opción al primer select
select1.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
// si el select 1 esta en el índice 1 (PROCEDE)
    if(select1.selectedIndex == 1) {
// indicamos que el select 2 no es un campo requerido
      select2.attributes['required'] = '';      
// habilitamos el select2 
      select2.disabled=false;
    }else {
// indicamos que el select 2 es un campo requerido
      select2.attributes['required'] = 'required';
// deshabilitamos el select 2
      select2.disabled=true;
    }
});
```